# How is this argument passed in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I've seen this code snippet but cannot quite figure out why it can successfully run.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "PowerShell.exe",
            Arguments = @"-NoLogo -NoProfile ""Get-Content Queries.txt"" | Set-Content Output.tsv"
        };

        Console.WriteLine(startInfo.Arguments);

        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
}
```

If I try to execute `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile "Get-Content Queries.txt" | Set-Content Output.tsv` directly in the command prompt it would throw error messages but the above code snippet could successfully finish.

How are the double quotes in the code being handled?

Comment: Try giving full path to Queries.txt

Comment: @cheedep The error message I receive while executing this is 'Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. So I think it is related to command argument parsing instead of the relative location of the input files.

Comment: The equivalent to what you're doing in C# on the command line would be `powershell "-NoLogo -NoProfile ""Get-Content Queries.txt"" | Set-Content Output.tsv"`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot This throws an error message like: The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: If you just want to execute on command prompt you need to use powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile "Get-Content Queries.txt | Set-Content Output.tsv" why it is working with C# without the quotes, I have no clue.

Comment: I pasted the wrong thing, it's `powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile ""Get-Content Queries.txt" | Set-Content Output.tsv"`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Thanks Preston. This works! But why do we have an additional pair of quotes between the Powershell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line parameters are parsed using spaces as a delimiter which can be of course be a problem for things such as paths which have spaces e.g. `Get-Content Queries.txt`. So to get around this, any parameters enclosed in double quotes will avoid this type of parsing-by-space-delimiter.

**So why do the double quotes work?**

With the code in question, because the string is prefixed with the `@` string literal, the double quotes are allowed without escaping. A nice short post on how the `@` string literal modifier works (by Jon Skeet no less) can be found at [What does an @ before the start of a string literal mean?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx). To quote a sentence from that:

> It basically means, "don't apply any interpretations to characters until the next quote character is reached". So, a verbatim string literal can contain backslashes (without them being doubled-up) and even line separators. To get a double-quote (") within a verbatim literal, you need to just double it...

**But copying to the command-line manually doesn't work, what's different?**

So when copying this to the command-line, this won't work in exactly the same way because it doesn't include the extra step that `Process.Start()` takes in wrapping the arguments in (wait for it...) another quote! As described in [PowerShell and double quotes on the command line](http://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/powershell-and-double-quotes-on-the-command-line/):

> Here’s some ways to make this work properly:
>
> - Use single quotes:
>
>   `powershell.exe C:\Scripts\ParamCheck.ps1 -Something 'one two'`
> - Use a
>     backslash delimiter (even though PowerShell internally uses the
>     left-single-quote `):
>
>   `powershell.exe C:\Scripts\ParamCheck.ps1 -Something \"one two\"`
> - Use
>     three double quotes:
>
>   `powershell.exe C:\Scripts\ParamCheck.ps1 -Something """one two"""`

**References:**

- [What does an @ before the start of a string literal mean?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx)
- [PowerShell and double quotes on the command line](http://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/powershell-and-double-quotes-on-the-command-line/)
- [When Do I Have to Put Double Quotes Around Parameter Values?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nexthop/archive/2010/09/12/tipsusingquotes.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But why can the C# code execute successfully then?

Comment: Updated the answer. It's because of the `@` literal.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Matt. Let me try to formulate my question a bit nicer. I understand the verbatim literal and how this argument is being interpreted inside C#. So if I understand correctly the argument to PowerShell.exe should be -NoLogo -NoProfile "Get-Content Queries.txt" | Set-Content Output.tsv

Comment: But if I directly throw that command to command prompt it wouldn't execute. Why is that?

Comment: As the first item in the further references shows (`PowerShell and double quotes on the command line`), this can be translated to the command line by using single quotes or even triple quotes. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you say command prompt, do you mean cmd.exe?  If so, you are dealing with cmd.exe's parsing and it isn't handling the `|` very well e.g.:

```
C:\>dir | foo.txt
'foo.txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I try your command from a PowerShell V4 prompt, it works fine.  Also, the script executed in C# is using PowerShell's command line parsing and not cmd.exe's parsing.